# How to prepend item to laravel lists collection without reindexing?

Tags: php, laravel, oop, collections

Trying to pass a collectino to a form select in the view. The prepend method is re-indexing the collection and I'm losing the correct company ids.

```
$companies = Company::lists('name','id');
return $companies;

/*
 * {
 *     "3": "Test 123 ",
 *     "4": "wer"
 *  }
 */

$companies->prepend('Select a company');
return $companies;

/*
 * [
 *      "Select a company",
 *      "Test 123 ",
 *      "wer"
 * ]
 */
```

I'm looking in the Collection object at the prepend method now, here it is:

```
public function prepend($value, $key = null)
{
    $this->items = Arr::prepend($this->items, $value, $key);

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok I quickly found a solution. By passing a key for the second argument, I'm using 0, the method will maintain the original keys.

```
$companies->prepend('Select a company', 0);
return $companies;

 \*
  * {
  *     "0": "Select a company",
  *     "3": "Test 123 ",
  *     "4": "wer"
  * }
  *\
```